# Finding the length of items in a Tuple (python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, highest

I'm looking for a "for loop" that finds the length of each item and choose the largest number.

```
>>>T=[chicken, soda, candy]
>>>Highest = 0
>>>"for loop goes here"
>>>print (highest)
7
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: `T` is not a tuple, it's a list. Did you mean list or tuple?

Comment: T is not a tuple, the contents of T are not strings so they also don't have any real notion of length.

Comment: @jubjub Please refine your question, may be we can help then

Comment: Pretend T is a tuple , sorry for the confusion

Comment: No need to pretend! Simply change the brackets `[]` to `()` and it will in fact become a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around your strings (e.g. `"chicken"`), and the case of variables matters so `Highest` and `highest` are different. Also use round parentheses `()` for a tuple and square `[]` for a list.

A simple way to do this in Python is be to use `max()` to find the longest string, and `len()` to find the lengths, with the `for` keyword creating a generator expression:

```
T=("chicken", "soda", "candy")
Highest = max(len(x) for x in T)
print(Highest)
```

Slightly older versions of Python would use a list comprehension:

```
Highest = max([len(x) for x in T])
```

erip's answer showed how to use a for loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

T is not a tuple, but a list. You can find out by doing `print(type(T))`. Try to read up on lists and Python programming in general, there are quite a few good resources available. If you want T to be a Tuple, simply change the brackets `[]` to regular `()` parenthesis like this `T = ("chicken", "soda", "candy")`, looping through it works the same way as mentioned below, so no need to change any of that.

The elements in your list `T` needs to be some kind of type or variable. What you are looking for is probably a String. To create the words as the String type, put it in double quotes like this `"chicken"`.

Heres what I suspect that you are looking for:

```
T = ["chicken", "soda" ,"candy"]
Highest = 0
for word in T:
    lengthOfWord = len(word)
    if lengthOfWord > Highest:
        Highest = lengthOfWord
print(Highest)
```

You can also check out a live version [here](https://repl.it/B2n1/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can create  list of lengths with the following:

```
[len(i) for i in T]
```

You can then call `max` on an iterable, which will return the maximum element.

Putting this together you have:

```
print(max([len(i) for i in T]))
```

If you want a `for-loop` explicitly, you can use this:

```
max_length = 0

for i in T:
  max_length = max(len(i), max_length))

print(max_length)
```

Note these both work for `list`s and `tuple`s.

Answer (score -2):

The question is not clear.
But I hope this will help you.

```
T = ('chicken', 'soda', 'candy')

Highest = 0

for i in range(0, len(T)):
    if len(T[i]) > int(Highest):
        Highest = len(T[i])

print ("Highest is %d" % Highest)
```